# Laravel OAuth2 authentication for Django Site

Tags: django, laravel, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, laravel-passport

I am building a Django application and I need to connect to an existing external Laravel site to authenticate users. Basically to have two different platforms, but users only have one set of credentials. Also - users should be able to sign up on the Django, and their user is created in the Laravel DB.

The Laravel site has Laravel Passport (OAuth2 based) installed because it uses it for a Flutter app.

I know that [REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/auth-remote-user/) is "the Django way" of achieving external auth but, I don't know where to go from there. If it makes a difference, the Django app will be a full REST application using DRF because its frontend will be ReactJS.

Can anyone explain how to achieve external auth with Django, particularly when the authentication server is OAuth2 based? Or better yet, how it can work with Laravel Passport in particular.

Thanks