# I wanna use other backend to authenticate my backend

Tags: django, authentication

I'm building an api server-side on Django. There is a Laravel server with the authentications of my user. I need authenticate my user with Laravel, because I dont want to make other db on Django with the same users.

How can I customize the django to authenticate this way ?

P.S.: Laravel is using bearer token. I need to keep the token on session after validate ?

Comment: unless you find one that someone else has published, I think you'll be writing your own custom one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: similar question without answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824384/laravel-oauth2-authentication-for-django-site